# How to solve unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on `browser` object issue?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ui-automation, webdriver-io

Error:  `Unable to load spec files quite likely because they rely on` browser `object` that is not fully initialised.
`browser` object has only `capabilities` and some flags like `isMobile`.

**these scripts are working fine for Jasmine but not for Mocha**

Old Dependencies:-

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^6.6.0",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.3.1",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^6.6.0",
    "@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^6.6.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.6.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.6.0",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "chromedriver": "latest",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "jasmine-allure-reporter": "^1.0.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "path-dirname": "^1.0.2",
    "path-exists": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.2",
    "wdio-intercept-service": "^4.1.2"
}
```

**New dependencies:-**

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.8",
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.9.1",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.9.1",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^7.9.1",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.9.1",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.9.1",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.9.0",
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "chromedriver": "latest",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "path-dirname": "^1.0.2",
    "path-exists": "^4.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.2.0",
    "wdio-intercept-service": "^4.1.7"
}
```

Can someone let me know what can be an issue? The new dependencies are up to date. most of the scripts are working but for some scripts, it gives this error. also, JSON object gives unexpected data which was not the case before.

Comment: have you found an answer for this issue?